# Ajuda com search

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5

Tenho um campo de busca simples abaixo, que quando é usado retorna com um link semelhante a:`meusite.com/search?q=minhabusca`. Preciso que ele retorne assim:`meusite.com/search?q=minhabusca&by-date=true`, para que as postagens sempre sejam mostradas classificadas por datas. Como posso fazer?

```
<form action='/search' method='get'>
 <input autocomplete='off' name='q' placeholder=' O que procura?' size='40' type='text'/>
 <button type='submit'>buscar</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adicione um `input` escondido no seu `form`. Basta adicionar o atributo `hidden`, dessa forma o input não irá aparecer para o usuário, mas ainda assim seu valor será enviado no `submit` do form.

```html
<form action='/search' method='get'>
 <input autocomplete='off' name='q' placeholder=' O que procura?' size='40' type='text'/>
 <input name='by-date' value='true' hidden/>
 <button type='submit'>buscar</button>
</form>
```